# Output order with process substitution

Tags: shell, io-redirection, file-descriptors, process-substitution

This is what I usually do to run `grep` and `wc` on a file without having to scan it twice

```
<file.txt  tee >(grep LITERAL) >(wc -l) >/dev/null
```

However, this yields

```
EXEC LITERAL
32
```

sometimes and

```
32
EXEC LITERAL
```

at other times.
(The output from `grep` precedes the output from `wc` in the first instance and vice versa in the second.)

On the other hand, with redirections and file descriptors

```
{ { <file.txt tee /dev/fd/3 | grep LITERAL >&4; } 3>&1 | wc -l ;} 4>&1
```

I always seem to get

```
EXEC LITERAL
32
```

I prefer that the output order be predictable but is it guaranteed with the second approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both

```
<file.txt  tee >(grep LITERAL) >(wc -l) >/dev/null
```

And:

```
{ { <file.txt tee /dev/fd/3 | grep LITERAL >&4; } 3>&1 | wc -l ;} 4>&1
```

All of `tee`, `grep` and `wc` are started concurrently. What matters then is what happens at the end.

`wc` will only print the result when it sees end-of-file on its standard input. In the first case, that's when `tee` exits, because then `tee` will close its `fd` on the other end of the pipe that `wc` is reading from (started by process substitution). There's no guarantee that `grep` will have read all its input by that time, let alone written its output (given that pipes can hold quite a large amount of data and that `wc` will likely be faster than `grep`)

In the second case, `wc` will see end-of-file when all the writers to the pipe it is reading from have closed their end of the pipe. In that case though, there are several writers. `tee` (via its fd open on `/dev/fd/3` and via its fd 3) and `grep` which also has its `fd` 3 open to the pipe to `wc` (though it is not making any use of it, let alone write to it). The inner `{` will likely cause an extra subshell process that will also have a `fd` 3 open and will wait for both `tee` and `grep`.

That means that `wc` will only write its line number after `grep` has exited.

Had you written it the proper way, that is by closing the fds that didn't need open:

```
{ { <file.txt tee /dev/fd/3 4>&- | 
   grep LITERAL >&4 3>&- 4>&-; } 3>&1 | wc -l 4>&-;} 4>&1
```

Then the order would not have been guaranteed in shells that optimise out the subshell process. However, the only shell that I know that does is `ksh93` but `ksh93` uses socket pairs for pipes, so `/dev/fd/3` won't work there on Linux at least.

To see what processes are running, you can replace `grep` with `ps`:

```
$ { { <file.txt tee /dev/fd/3 4>&- | ps -H >&4 3>&- 4>&-; } 3>&1 | wc -l 4>&-;} 4>&1
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8727 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
 8815 pts/5    00:00:00   bash
 8817 pts/5    00:00:00     tee
 8818 pts/5    00:00:00     ps
 8816 pts/5    00:00:00   wc
```

With `bash`, you can see that extra shell process, and you can see it also has the pipe opened on fd 3 with:

```
$ (p=$BASHPID; { { <file.txt tee /dev/fd/3 4>&- | lsof -ag "$p" -d3 >&4 3>&- 4>&-; } 3>&1 | wc -l 4>&-;} 4>&1)
COMMAND  PID PGID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
bash    9843 9842 chazelas    3w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 153304 pipe
tee     9845 9842 chazelas    3w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 153304 pipe
lsof    9846 9842 chazelas    3r   DIR    0,3        0      1 /proc
```

Comment: Thanks. In your "proper example", what does `grep LITERAL >&4 3>&- 4>&-` mean, the fd 4 appears to be both used and closed?

Comment: @1_CR, after `>&4`, short for `1>&4`, `grep`'s fd 1 and 4 point to the same resource (the shell's initial stdout). `grep` does not need to have its fd 4 open to anything. It does not do anything with it, so we close it with `4>&-`

Comment: That last command-line is cryptic magic.

Answer (score -1):

To get a predictable order use

```
(<file.txt  tee >(grep LITERAL) >(wc -l) >/dev/null)|sort
```

Comment: Perhaps i wasn't clear enough. I meant predictable order in terms of order of command outputs (ie output from grep before output from wc). I don't need the combined output sorted

Comment: just found http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping, it tells me that with the {} operators you make sure (in this case) that you first do <file.txt tee /dev/fd/3 | grep LITERAL >&4; and when this is done you call wc, so to answer your original question, yes it is guaranteed to my understanding

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk could you add the extra info you found to your answer?

Comment: I found http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping